# mySQL queries inside a for loop within a promise.resolve doesn't work

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, promise

```
const getSelectStations = (stations => {
  let query = 'SELECT * FROM stops INNER JOIN stations ON stops.station_id  = stations.id WHERE stops.line_id IN (?)';
  let collection = [];

  const getStops = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
      connection.query(query, [stations[i]], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return err;
        } else {
          collection.push(results);
        }
      })
    }
  }

  Promise.resolve(getStops())
    .then(() => {
      console.log('AFTERRRRRRRRRRRRR', collection); //results in initial value of []
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  })
```

I've been stuck for a few hours on trying to figure this out as well as trying other methods. I feel like there's a gap in my knowledge regarding promises here. What I'm trying to do is run some mysql queries through express for a variable amount of numbers inside the `stations` variable. My current understanding to what I have coded is that I'm calling my `getStops()` function inside of a `Promise.resolve()` which to me means that then `.then()` after won't execute until that promise is resolved meaning that all my queries have been called and returned. I am pushing the result of each query into a variable called `collection` which is outside the scope of my `getStops` function. I expected my `collection` variable to have all the query results in the `.then` call but it returns `[]`. I have consoled logged out the results from my query and they return the desired data. From what I'm seeing while I troubleshoot is that either my `console.log(collection)` inside of my `.then` is being called before the promise resolves which doesn't make sense to me leading me to think that I am incorrectly using Promise here or I have an unrelated error to my Promise.

Comment: You have a false expectation of `Promise.resolve()`. The expression `Promise.resolve(getStops())` will promise-wrap whatever is returned by `getStops()`. It won't force `getStops()` into the desired behaviour - namely to return a Promise that will resolve when all the `connection.query()` queries have completed.

Comment: To save me having to search for it, can you provide a link to the API for `connection.query()` please? I need to know whether or not it returns (or can be made to return) a Promise.